# Diffifulty with JavaScript on Syntax Error

Tags: javascript

I am getting this.... Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list... when I try to enter this code in and I can not figure out how to fix it.

```
// flight_costs.js

function flightCosts() {

    const cost_per_checked_bag = 50; 
    const typical_flight_speed = 575;
    const hours_in_airport = 5; 

    var traveler_payrate_per_hour = Number(document.getElementById("traveler_payrate_per_hour").value);
    console.log("traveler_payrate_per_hour" + traveler_payrate_per_hour);
    var number_of_travelers = Number(document.getElementById("number_of_travelers").value);
    console.log("number_of_travelers" + number_of_travelers);

    //Flight Costs
    var miles_flying = Number(document.getElementById("miles_flying").value);
    console.log("miles_flying" + miles_flying);
    var flight_cost = Number(document.getElementById("flight_cost").value)
    console.log("flight_cost" + flight_cost);
    var flight_transit_cost = Number(document.getElementById("flight_transit_cost").value);
    console.log("flight_transit_cost" + flight_transit_cost);
    var flight_discount = Number(document.getElementById("flight_discount").value);
    console.log("flight_discount" + flight_discount);
    var flight_amenities = Number(addCheckboxValues("flight_amenities") ||0;
    console.log("flight_amenities" + flight_amenities);
    var checked_bags_per_traveler = Number(document.getElementById("checked_bags_per_traveler").value);
    console.log("checked_bags_per_traveler" + checked_bags_per_travelers);
    var in_flight_amenities = Number(addCheckboxValues("in_flight_amenities") ||0;
    console.log("in_flight_amenities" + in_flight_amenities);

    var total_traveler_flight_cost = flight_cost * number_of_travelers;
    console.log("total_traveler_flight_cost" + total_traveler_flight_cost);

    var time_of_flight = miles_flying / typical_flight_speed;
    console.log("time_of_flight" + time_of_flight);

    var total_amenities = (flight_amenities + in_flight_amenities) * number_of_travelers;
    console.log("total_amenities" + total_amenities);

    var total_payrate_cost = (traveler_payrate_per_hour * (time_of_flight * 2) + hours_in_airport) ) * number_of_travelers;
    console.log("total_payrate_cost" + total_payrate_cost);

    var total_flight_checked_bags_cost = check_bags_per_traveler * cost_per_checked_bag * number_of_travelers;
    console.log("total_flight_checked_bags_cost" + total_flight_checked_bags_cost);


    var total_flight_cost = total_traveler_flight_cost + total_amenities +
                            total_flight_checked_bags_cost - flight_discount +
                            total_payrate_cost;
    console.log("total_flight_cost" + total_flight_cost);


    return total_flight_cost;
}
```

Comment: `var flight_amenities = Number(addCheckboxValues("flight_amenities") ||0;` and `var in_flight_amenities = Number(addCheckboxValues("in_flight_amenities") ||0;` each miss 1 closing )

Comment: Stack Overflow is not your personal debugger. We're trying to build a repository of good Q&As that will help people in the future.

Comment: You already have the good habit of using your JavaScript console. That's great! But next to this error message (which is pretty self explanatory), it should say on which line the error was detected. Next time, take a look at that before asking a question here.

Comment: It's telling you exactly what's wrong. You're missing a `)` somewhere. Remember: for every `(` there must always be a matching `)`. Count them out and find the missing one(s).

Comment: If you write your code in an IDE or decent editor, it will automatically create matching parentheses, or highlight the places where they're missing. Get yourself a better editor.

Answer (score 3):

`var flight_amenities = Number(addCheckboxValues("flight_amenities") ||0;`
you are missing a closing bracket after ("flight_amenities") there.

**Edit**

also, as fvu stated, at 
`in_flight_amenities = Number(addCheckboxValues("in_flight_amenities")`

Comment: And others in the rest of the code (line 21, 25, 37...)

Answer (score 2):

Put simply, it's because many of your parentheses just don't close properly. I fixed 3 spots.

```
function flightCosts() {

    const cost_per_checked_bag = 50; 
    const typical_flight_speed = 575;
    const hours_in_airport = 5; 

    var traveler_payrate_per_hour = Number(document.getElementById("traveler_payrate_per_hour").value);
    console.log("traveler_payrate_per_hour" + traveler_payrate_per_hour);
    var number_of_travelers = Number(document.getElementById("number_of_travelers").value);
    console.log("number_of_travelers" + number_of_travelers);

    //Flight Costs
    var miles_flying = Number(document.getElementById("miles_flying").value);
    console.log("miles_flying" + miles_flying);
    var flight_cost = Number(document.getElementById("flight_cost").value)
    console.log("flight_cost" + flight_cost);
    var flight_transit_cost = Number(document.getElementById("flight_transit_cost").value);
    console.log("flight_transit_cost" + flight_transit_cost);
    var flight_discount = Number(document.getElementById("flight_discount").value);
    console.log("flight_discount" + flight_discount);
    var flight_amenities = Number(addCheckboxValues("flight_amenities")) ||0;
    console.log("flight_amenities" + flight_amenities);
    var checked_bags_per_traveler = Number(document.getElementById("checked_bags_per_traveler").value);
    console.log("checked_bags_per_traveler" + checked_bags_per_travelers);
    var in_flight_amenities = Number(addCheckboxValues("in_flight_amenities")) ||0;
    console.log("in_flight_amenities" + in_flight_amenities);

    var total_traveler_flight_cost = flight_cost * number_of_travelers;
    console.log("total_traveler_flight_cost" + total_traveler_flight_cost);

    var time_of_flight = miles_flying / typical_flight_speed;
    console.log("time_of_flight" + time_of_flight);

    var total_amenities = (flight_amenities + in_flight_amenities) * number_of_travelers;
    console.log("total_amenities" + total_amenities);

    var total_payrate_cost = (traveler_payrate_per_hour * (time_of_flight * 2) + hours_in_airport) * number_of_travelers;
    console.log("total_payrate_cost" + total_payrate_cost);

    var total_flight_checked_bags_cost = check_bags_per_traveler * cost_per_checked_bag * number_of_travelers;
    console.log("total_flight_checked_bags_cost" + total_flight_checked_bags_cost);


    var total_flight_cost = total_traveler_flight_cost + total_amenities +
                            total_flight_checked_bags_cost - flight_discount +
                            total_payrate_cost;
    console.log("total_flight_cost" + total_flight_cost);


    return total_flight_cost;
}
```

You would do a lot of stuff like this:
`Number(addCheckboxValues("flight_amenities") ||0;`. But you notice how there is no closing parenthesis?

Then you have this line:
    `var total_payrate_cost = (traveler_payrate_per_hour * (time_of_flight * 2) + hours_in_airport) ) * number_of_travelers;`

Notice how there is an extra closing parenthesis that does nothing?

The error means exactly what it said.

Answer (score -1):

Also on this line:

```
var flight_cost = Number(document.getElementById("flight_cost").value)
```

You are missing the termination **;**